# What does @include('partials.register') do?

Tags: php, laravel

This is an example of code in using that code. I just want to know the use of @include('partials.register') do in this code.

```
@if (Auth::check()==true)
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> Welcome ,
            {{ auth()->user()->name }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="{{ route('customer.edit',auth()->user()->id) }}">                                      
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
                    {{ __('views.welcome.logout') }}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          @endif 
          @endif 
          @endif  
        </ul>   
    </div>       
    </div>  
  @include('partials.login')
    @include('partials.register')
```

Comment: It includes the file `partials/register.blade.php`?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... I would highly suggest reading the documentation for Blade Templates as this is all there

Answer (score 1):

> Blade's @include directive allows you to include a Blade view from within another view.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews

Answer (score -1):

if  you have a short part of code  repeated in many blade views you can put it in special blade  view and then include it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0nIKPyt51w&list=PLlxQJeQRaKDSnp4hbA3nJj_OnB0SCQLBU&index=9